# Change all the input values at once

Tags: scale, vector-mapping

I've seen people change the X, Y ans Z inputs in the mapping node all at once. How is that done?
In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebx2qbBlvh0&list=WL&index=2&t=57s) tutorial, Andrew Price does it at 7:44

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>LMB</kbd> click on the first property, drag your cursor down to the last one and you can enter one value for all of them.